# Display heatmap legend and regular legend together in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, legend, heatmap

How do I display both a heatmap legend and regular legend with highcharts?

I've got a heatmap I've made in highcharts that also has spline series laid over it. I love the special color axis legend that shows for the heatmap, but unfortunately it means none of the spline series show up with it.

The other series are more important, and I can just prevent the heatmap from showing on the legend if I want them instead... but is it possible to display both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to show color-axis and regular legend items in Highcharts, you need to only enable `showInLegend` option for a specific series.

```
  series: [{
    showInLegend: true,
    ...
  }, {
    showInLegend: true,
    ...
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/amw63xke/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.showInLegend

Comment: How... is it that simple...? I never even thought to try this because showInLegend defaults to true, so it should do exactly this by default. And yet this works! This answer is so obvious and yet so very not. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Megan Bores, Using `colorAxis` hides all other elements related to this specific color-axis in legend, but only if `showInLegend` is not manually enabled for them.